# PHP randomly selecting css files on page load

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

I have been looking through SO to try to find out this answer, and unfortunately I am not well versed in  php yet. So I have adapted something I found on here as well (although not confirmed working).

I'm trying to get the php file to randomly select and apply a css file in a particular folder (/colors).

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$css_dir = '../colors';
$files   = array();

foreach(glob($css_dir.'/*.css') as $file) 
{
    $array[] = $file;
}

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . array_rand($files, 1) . ' id="colors">';
?>
```

I need it to essentially output this line (with the color file randomly selected)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colors/blue.css" id="colors" />
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Read the documentation for the [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) function. You cannot just use functions without knowing what they do, and expect everything to magically work.

Comment: I read the documentation and still don't really see why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Then you have not read it properly. Look at the [Return Values](http://dk2.php.net/array_rand#refsect1-function.array-rand-returnvalues) section. Read it more than once if you do not get it the first time.

Comment: Using the code below, without '1' since array_rand returns a single item, which should work. But thanks for being helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns a random key, which you can use to echo a random entry inside the array.

Example:

```
$array[array_rand($array)];
```

Applying it:

```
$css_dir = '../colors'; // provided this is the correct path where your css files reside
$files = array();

foreach(glob($css_dir.'/*.css') as $file) {
    $files[] = $file;
}

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $files[array_rand($files)] . '" id="colors">';
```

Comment: Will this automatically add it to the head section? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @LordSnow just put this logic where you normally place stylesheets

Comment: Sorry for the questions, so don't put it in it's on php file but directly to the head of the site?

Comment: @LordSnow yes thats one way, of course, there are like myriads of ways to apply this logic, also you could create another separate php file and then create this code as a function with a return value of the name of the file, include that php file up top, then just `echo function_name()` inside the head

Comment: It still doesn't echo out for some reason. I'm going to try to set up a debugger.